# Can DNS be configured to use multiple targets for a single CNAME?

Tags: dns, dns-servers, cname

My host has various CNAME target server

eg

```
server1.hostinger.net
server2.hostinger.net
server3.hostinger.net
server4.hostinger.net
server5.hostinger.net
```

Is a good thing configure the same www.mysite.com cname with al these targets?
Something like

```
CNAME          | TTL   |Target
www.mysite.com | 1440  |server1.hostinger.net
www.mysite.com | 1440  |server2.hostinger.net
www.mysite.com | 1440  |server3.hostinger.net
www.mysite.com | 1440  |server4.hostinger.net
```

or I must use only a single target?

Comment: Does your site exist on all of these servers? If so, then Yes you can do this. If not, then No. You would have to reference only the server your site sites on.

Answer (score 2):

According to the standards you can have multiple DNS records for the same host name as long as they point to different endpoints. This is the same for A, AAAA, CNAME, MX, etc. As long as your site exists on all the servers you are pointing to then you can configure CNAME records for each and every hostinger.net server.